# How to strip specific characters and words from String

Tags: php

I'm trying to strip a list of specified characters and words from various string variants.

Here are the possible strings:

```
* - integer from 0 - 100

quantity_c_size_*_con
quantity_c_size_*_con_c
quantity_c_size_*_con_b
quantity_size_*
quantity_size_*_chain
```

Depending on the variant above; I want to strip out the underscores and some of the words to leave just the integer.

```
Example - quantity_c_size_38_con     =      Size 38
```

Could anybody tell me how I would perform this action?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at `preg_replace()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be:

```
function stripStuff($string)
{
    $parts = explode("_", $string);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i++)
    {
        if(is_numeric($parts[$i]))
        {
            return($parts[$i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the sort of thing you're after?

```
// Remove anything that's not a number.
$outputString = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $inputString);
```